# SQLite fetch until

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a question about SQL.

I have the following sample table called `Records`:

| record_id | subject | start_timestamp | end_timestamp | interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Start Product 2 | 2021-04-21T16:22:39 | 2021-04-21T16:23:40 | 0.97 |
| 3 | error 1 | 2021-04-21T16:25:44 | 2021-04-21T16:25:54 | 10.0 |
| 4 | End Product 2 | 2021-04-21T16:30:13 | 2021-04-21T16:30:14 | 0.97 |
| 5 | Start Product 1 | 2021-04-21T16:35:13 | 2021-04-21T16:35:13 | 0.6 |
| 6 | End Product 1 | 2021-04-21T16:36:13 | 2021-04-21T16:36:13 | 0.45 |

First I select all the items that have `start` in there subject with and are not in the table `BackupTO` (for now the table `BackupTO` is not important):

```sql
SELECT Records.record_id, Records.start_timestamp, Records.interval FROM Records
LEFT JOIN BackupTO ON BackupTO.record_id = Records.record_id
WHERE BackupTO.record_id IS NULL AND Records.log_type = 1 AND Records.subject LIKE '%start%'
```

When I ran this we get:

| record_id | start_timestamp | interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-04-21T16:22:39 | 0.97 |
| 5 | 2021-04-21T16:35:13 | 0.6 |

Oke, all good now comes my question, I fetch this in Python and loop through the data, first I calculate the product number based on the `interval` with:

```py
product = round(result[2] / 0.5)
```

So a interval of 0.97 is product 2, and a interval of 0.6,0.45 is product 1, all great!

So I know `record_id 2` is product 2 and I want to execute a sql query thats returns all items starting from `record_id 2`  untils its find a items that has `%end%2` in its name (the 2 is for product 2, could also be product 1).
For example its finds  `Start Product 2` I get a list with `record_id` 3 and 4.
I want to get all items from the start until end.
So it gets me a list like this, this are all the items found under `Start Product 2` until `%end%2` was found. For product 1, it just would return just `record_id 6`, because there is nothing between the start and stop.

| record_id | start_timestamp | interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-04-21T16:22:39 | 10.0 |
| 4 | 2021-04-21T16:35:13 | 0.97 |

[image]

I tried OFFSET and FETCH, but I couldnt get it to work, somebody that could help me out here?

Comment: The description second part (ie from record_id 2) is a bit confusing. Can you please simplify and make it more clear what you actually are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your query as a CTE and join it to the table `Records`.
Then with `MIN()` window function find the `record_id` up to which you want the rows returned:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT r.* 
  FROM Records r LEFT JOIN BackupTO b
  ON b.record_id = r.record_id
  WHERE b.record_id IS NULL AND r.log_type = 1 AND r.subject LIKE '%start%'
)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT r.*, 
         MIN(CASE WHEN r.subject LIKE '%end%' THEN r.record_id END) OVER () id_end
  FROM Records r INNER JOIN cte c
  ON r.record_id > c.record_id
  WHERE c.record_id = ?
)
WHERE COALESCE(record_id <= id_end, 1)
```

Change `?` to `2` or `5` for each case.

If you have the `record_id`s returned by your query, it is simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT r.*, 
         MIN(CASE WHEN r.subject LIKE '%end%' THEN r.record_id END) OVER () id_end
  FROM Records r
  WHERE r.record_id > ?
)
WHERE COALESCE(record_id <= id_end, 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ce7970805dff8d89cd1b7fc26b230bbd).